# Copy Openstack instance volume manually

Tags: openstack, volume, devstack, dd

I have a server with an Openstack deployment on top. I've created an instance with a 10 Gb volume and an ubuntu image.

I would like to copy the volume manually using `dd` in order to analyze it. The volumes are supposed to be located in `/dev` with the names `dm-x`, where x is a number and the ID for each volume can be identified to the instance it belongs to from the Openstack dashboard and looking into the symlink in `/dev/stack-volumes-lvmdriver1-id`.

Well, once I've dd'd the desired `dm-x` into a folder in my home directory, I obtain a DOS/MBR file but, shouldn't it be a logical volume?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stackoverflow, but it can be answered quickly. A logical volume is a device file. The only way you can create a device file is with the `mknod` command. `dd` only copies data from one file to another; if the target file doesn't exist, `dd` creates a regular file. If you need a device file, use `losetup` to create a loop device.

Comment: So to create a copy of the device can i just create a new logical volume and clone it using mknod and losetup?

Comment: You don't need a logical volume. `losetup -f FILENAME` will create a device named `/dev/loopX`, where FILENAME is the name of the file you created with `dd`, and X is a number.